# export Swift var for Objective-C only

Tags: swift, objective-c, bridging-header

My Swift library API has a public property of type `enum`:

```swift
public enum Animal : String, Codable {
  case Dog
  case Cat
}

public var pet: Animal
```

The `enum` is not exported as `@objc`, but I need to access this property from Objective-C. So, I add a computed property

```swift
@objc public var petAsString: String {
  get { return String(reflecting: pet) }
  set { pet = newValue == "Cat" ? Animal.Cat : Animal.Dog }
}
```

Can I *hide* this property from the Swift consumers of my library? Or, maybe, there is a better way to let it be used from Objective-C, without the ugly 'AsString' suffix?

---

**Update:** *Sorry for misrepresenting my root problem*. I chose to go through all this trouble because I did not understand then that Swift `typealias` lets me export to Objective-C a long and ugly but unambiguous `enum AlexPetLib_Animal`, while all my and third party Swift code can still use properly namespaced `Animal` alias:

```swift
public typealias Animal = AlexPetLib_Animal
@objc public enum AlexPetLib_Animal : Int, Codable {
  case Dog
  case Cat
}
```

No extra changes were required for my library code; the Swift app that uses the library only had to be recompiled.

Comment: Why would you use `String(reflecting:)` instead of `rawValue`? You don't need any typealiases, you can just specify a name for Objective-C using `@objc(AlexPetLib_Animal)`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks, this `@objc(AlexPetLib_Animal)` is what I was missing! As for `String(reflecting:)` – this was just an illustration, please ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

An enum that has an integral raw value type can be `@objc`, so you can just use `Int` as `Animal`'s raw value type instead:

```
@objc
public enum Animal : Int, Codable {
  case dog
  case cat
}
```

To replicate the behaviour of the `String` raw value type in Swift, add these members:

```
var stringValue: String {
    switch self {
    case .cat: return "Cat"
    case .dog: return "Dog"
    }
}

init?(stringValue: String) {
    switch stringValue {
    case "Cat": self = .cat
    case "Dog": self = .dog
    default: return nil
    }
}

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let string = try container.decode(String.self)
    if let animal = Animal(stringValue: string) {
        self = animal
    } else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Expected cat or dog!")
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encode(stringValue)
}
```

Unlike the "writing two versions of each thing that uses `Animal` approach", those four members are the only extra things you need. After that, you will be able to mark everything that uses `Animal` as `@objc` (assuming it doesn't use other non `@objc` stuff of course).

An edge case is when passing `Animal` to methods that accept a generic `RawRepresentable`, it will use the `Int` raw value, but I don't that happens often...

Comment: The main reason for not exporting the enum was to avoid namespace clashes. I did not want to have `Animal` prefixed as `AlexPetLibAnimal` everywhere in my and 3rd party swift code, only because somebody could use it in Objective C. I think that Swift's `typealias` can be good enough for me.

Comment: @AlexCohn you can have it exported as a different name in ObjC. Try `@objc(AlexPetLibAnimal)` on the enum.

Comment: Same as @Sulthan suggested, thanks. It's even cleaner than typealias: it uses `SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED` which may be helpful, still learning what this `__attribute__((swift_name("Animal")))` [does](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CToSwiftNameTranslation.md).

Comment: @AlexCohn Ah, I didn't see Sulthan's comment. I'm not sure what you are talking about regarding `__attribute__((swift_name("Animal")))`. Aren't you exposing a _swift_ enum to ObjC? That should be totally irrelevant if I understand correctly.

Comment: The way Swift exports its enum (in the `AlexPetLib-Swift.h` file) as `typedef SWIFT_ENUM_NAMED(NSInteger, AlexPetLibAnimal, "Animal", open) `. This macro injects the `__attribute__`. You are right, this attribute is intended for objc2swift integration, but when I try to use my lib as xcframework via CocoaPod, the swift compiler is looking exactly at this attribute! Until now, I found one glitch with that: an enum inside a class gets an alias that is outside the class, but this happens with 'normal' `@objc`, too.

Answer (score 0):

*To sum it up*: there is no trick that will hide a Swift **var** or **func** from Swift consumers, but it is possible not only to hide it from Obj-C consumers, but also expose it to them under a different name, using `@objc(AnotherName)` pattern.

For my specific use case, this allowed me to expose the **enum** to Obj-C under a library-prefixed name, which is definitely a better choice, compared to using unprotected string-based API.